# Infer return value from promise in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a very simple function that takes two arguments - **node object** and **async function** that somehow processes given node and returns processed node which can be anything.

I would like to make it generic and infer type from async function. This is my try but TS is complaining and I don't really understand why.

```
// ensure that callback is of a correct type
type NodeCallback<H> = H extends (node: Node) => Promise<infer R> ? (node: Node) => Promise<R> : never

// retrieve return value
type NodeCallbackReturnValue<H> = H extends (node: Node) => Promise<infer R> ? R : never


const myAsyncFunction = <_, C>(node: Node, cb: NodeCallback<C>) => {
  return cb(node)
}


myAsyncFunction(document, (node: Node) => Promise.resolve(node.nodeType))
```

Playground available [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFMDsGcFcCdygC4AsCGzQGN0Bs8AjdbAa1AEtpQB7AM1HRxvkWy2QE8AHcAKC69QAORoATcAGF8REqQA8ACQB8oALyhFEAB7IoY6gApI48AC4RpgJTrVABXg0AtlXDyKkOuHigASqoB+UGNTC1EJGzV7RxdoN39QC0hwADdvPj4QUERkeApUpByESFAU-Fh+QSRwqRliMl9wZGKANXK3FXVNHT1IA2CTCTDrW1AHZ1d3T28-QL9E0GS0+Ay+bBoYLCdOAEFoTkhsADFYQ+QKDa75AH0AGlBJZRChywl77EJhiWkCeoVHyKqADefFA2SaxRwhGe4CsfAAvqttnsDsdTuwLpBDGIaNhYE4oMh7jCvrDRuNYuAAHSIaA0PBpGFUwbgAAqPFhViAA)

Comment: Why do you need that conditional type. This seems to work https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFMDsGcFcCdygC4AsCGzQGN0Bs8AjdbAa1AEtpQB7AM1HRxvkWy2QE8AHcAKC69QAORoATcAGF8REqQA8ACQB8oALwAKSOPAAuEToCU61QAV4NALZVwS5Xz4hQiZPArgAbkhcJIoD-iw-IJIohLSBMRkAErgyL4AaoG2KuqgihAAHshQYtRaOvph4MZqZhbW0LYUkHTg8KDRqgD8jaD6kJ71DnzYNDBYlpwAgtCckNgAYrATyBT9afKSWTmQeQYSygUSRToANDiEu+EyUQqSyqWqAN58oM5xvofbJXwAvj1Do+NTM+zzkA0Yho2FgligyAOL2OJRMoHMVhsADpENAaHgvC9DIYgA

Comment: my example may be confusing, the callback  param can return anything not just node. Your example forces callback to return always Node

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternative solution without explicit generic

```js
type NodeCallback<T> = (node: Node) => Promise<T>

const myAsyncFunction = <R,>(node: Node, cb: NodeCallback<R>) => {
  return cb(node)
}

const result = myAsyncFunction(
  document,
  (node: Node) => Promise.resolve(node.nodeType)
) // Promise<number>
```

I don't think we need conditional types in `NodeCallback` type at all, since TS is able to infer the type

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gEwgYQIYBt0CNUGMDWAPACoB8UAvFABQB2iEAXLAwJSXkAKATnALYBLAM4QSpAFDjccWkOBQ%20IAIJCQtXADEAruuACZlKIQBKAGlJ0GzeElNRcWawzSYcBE6XYVyAb3FQobghgLW5aeyxLJFZxAF9JaVl5IKEtdHkqRRU1TR1cPRlqBDhcLT4IWmA7KKYWaI4oHn5hCAA6FLh0ADcIGtb6JGJwCFZWIA)

[Here](https://catchts.com/callbacks)  you can find more information about working with callbacks

Comment: This is a really neat solution. I didn't really know that one can do this in TS. Thanks :)

Comment: @Joozty here https://catchts.com/callbacks you can find more information about working with callbacks

Answer (score 2):

That's because the implicitly declared generic type is `unknown` in `myAsyncFunction(...)`, and it can't inferred to other type

You can solve it by following:

```
// change
type NodeCallback<H> = H extends (node: Node) => Promise<infer R> ? (node: Node) => Promise<R> : never
// into
type NodeCallback<H> = H extends (node: Node) => Promise<infer R> ? H : never
```

Or

```
const myAsyncFunction = <C,>(node: Node, cb: NodeCallback<C>) => {
  return cb(node)
}

type T = (node: Node) => Promise<number>
myAsyncFunction<T>(document, (node: Node) => Promise.resolve(node.nodeType))
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=74#code/PTAEFMDsGcFcCdygC4AsCGzQGN0Bs8AjdbAa1AEtpQB7AM1HRxvkWy2QE8AHcAKC69QAORoATcAGF8REqQA8ACQB8oALyhFEAB7IoY6gApI48AC4RpgJTrVABXg0AtlXDyKkOuHigASqoB+TVALSHAAN28+PhBQRGR4CgikeIRIUHD8WH5BJFEJaQJiMl9wZDSANSy3FXVg8F19IxMJC3zwGzV7RxdoNw8vH39QIN8Q0DDI+Gi+bBoYLCdOAEFoTkhsADFYDeQKebr5AH0AGlBJZWNTNtMz7EIbgplihQvO1QBvPlA4srScQhXCRWPgAXxmS1W6y2O3Y+0ghjENGwsCcUGQZyB5kswNsoAczlcADpENAaHhIliiS1wAAVHgdKxAA)

Comment: Finally, above code would be simplified to one answer that like @captain-yossarian 's

Comment: I am kind of lost in the explanation why generic type would be `unknown`.  I don't understand what range do you mean?

Comment: @Joozty Maybe there are some issues in my description, let me correct it.